# NodeJS gRPC: "Method handler expected but not provided"

Tags: javascript, node.js, rpc, grpc

I plowed through the docs and haven't found a solution yet. The app is loosely based on the ["sayHello"-example](http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/node.html) from their docs but every time the code runs the warning `Method handler for /eventComm.DatabaseRPC/InsertSingleDocument expected but not provided` is returned.

My proto file:

```proto
service DatabaseRPC {
  rpc InsertSingleDocument (Doc) returns (Doc) {} 
}

message Doc {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
}
```

My gRPC Server:

```js
  function InsertSingleDocument (call, callback) {
    callback(null, {
      name: 'Hello ',
      id: 1
    })
  }
  let server = new grpc.Server()
  server.addProtoService(protoDef.DatabaseRPC.service, {
    InsertSingleDocument: InsertSingleDocument
  })
  server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure())
  server.start()
```

What is the problem with this code? Of course I already tried to [google the error](https://www.google.de/search?q=nodejs%20grpc%20methodhandler%20expected%20but%20not%20found&oq=nodejs%20grpc%20method%20handler%20expected%20but%20not%20found) but found no solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To conform with JavaScript naming conventions, methods should be provided with the first letter lowercased:

```
server.addProtoService(protoDef.DatabaseRPC.service, {
  insertSingleDocument: InsertSingleDocument
})
```

You can see this in the Hello World example you linked. The method is declared as `SayHello` in the proto file, but is passed to the server as `sayHello`.

Note: I agree that this is confusing, and [I will try to improve the situation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/10080).

Comment: Thank you. I totally missed the lowercasing in the example. Is it an issue with other languages too? Maybe it would help to enforce a naming scheme where all functions are declared with a starting lowercase letter in the proto file.

Comment: In multiple languages, there is some expectation that method names will follow that language's naming scheme, but those naming schemes may be different. The declaration you have in the proto file does match the naming convention for proto files.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Could that be added to the documentation? In big red letters. I like gRPC so far but I totally missed that bit when I read the [quick start guide](http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/node.html#update-a-grpc-service).